# Testing @future callouts

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, future

I've been scouring all the documentation, trailhead, and here and I can't get this to work.  I'm running into a wall in test class where I'm using the HttpCalloutMock method, but I can't return the response because my class that I am calling returns void and I'm getting "Illegal assignment from void to System.HttpResponse".  I can't make it not void because it is a @future callout.  Is there just another place I need to be looking?  I can post code if needed but I think this is more of a general question of testing @future callouts.

Edit:

Posting my code below.

Here is the class I am trying to get code coverage on (currently 0% despite everything I've tried)

```
public class PortalQuery {
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void portalGet(String match_id){

        //set Match Record        
        Match_Record__c mr = [SELECT Id, PODs__c
        FROM Match_Record__c 
        WHERE Match_ID__c = :match_id];

        System.debug(match_id);
        System.debug(mr.Id);

        //callout to Portal API
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('url here');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

        // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            system.debug('response = ' + res.getBody());
            String jsonContent = res.getBody();
            System.debug(jsonContent);

            //call JSON Utility to help with parse
            Util_JSONParser parser = Util_JSONParser.createParser(jsonContent);

            //parse out Match Record fields for updates
            String match_algorithm_version = parser.get('match_algorithm_version').Value;
            if(match_algorithm_version != NULL){
                Decimal mav = Decimal.valueOf(match_algorithm_version);
                mr.Match_Algorithm_Version_Number__c = mav; 
            }
        }
        mr.Last_Match_API_Update__c = System.now();
        update mr;
    }
}
```

RestResource that calls to class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/mrUpdate')
global with sharing class mrUpdate {

@HTTPPatch
//query SFDC Match Record from portal match_id
global static String updateMR(String match_id, String token){
    Match_Record__c mr = [SELECT Id, Send_POD__c
                            FROM Match_Record__c 
                           WHERE Match_ID__c = :match_id];
    System.debug('***Here is the MATCH ID*** ' + match_id);
    System.debug('!!!!Here is the TOKEN!!!!! ' + token);

    //call portal for MR fields
    if (token != 'some token'){
        PortalQuery.portalGet(match_id);
    }
    //call portal for PODs
    if (mr.Send_POD__c == TRUE){
        PortalQuery.podQuery(match_id);
    }

    return null;
    //call response method to show udpated Match Record json
    List <Match_Record__c> updatedMR = mrResponse.getUpdatedMR();
    return null;
}
```

}

And the test class

```
@isTest
public class portalQueryTest {
    @isTest 
    static void setData(){

        Match_Record__c mr = new Match_Record__c();
        List <Match_Record__c> mrList = new List <Match_Record__c>();
        String match_id = 'name';
        String token = 'token';

        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name = 'Account';
        insert account;

        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.FirstName = 'Contact';
        contact.LastName = 'Jones';
        contact.AccountId = account.Id;
        insert contact;

        Guardant_360_Sample__c sample = new Guardant_360_Sample__c();
        sample.Name = 'name';
        sample.Contact__c = contact.Id;
        sample.Account__c = account.Id;
        insert sample;

        mr.Name = 'name';
        mr.Match_ID__c = 'name';
        mr.Portal_Sample_ID__c = 'sample';
        mr.Last_Match_API_Update__c = System.now();

        insert mr;
        mrList.add(mr);

        POD__c pod = new POD__c();
        pod.Match_Record__c = mr.Id;
        insert pod;

        Test.startTest();
        //I am honestly totally lost at this point.  
        //I've looked at so many pages I'm not sure what to do here 
        //to get a json string into the class I'm trying to test.
        //I've tried the mockcallout, using a static resource, etc....        
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you care about the return value? I think seeing your code might be instructive.

Comment: Maybe I'm not needing it at all?  I'm just trying to get the class that calls out to receive a json string and parse it out as needed so I can get some code coverage.

Comment: Where is your `PortalQuery.portalGet` method invoked from? Is it called from a trigger when inserting a `Match_Record__c` record?

Comment: @D.S. ah, it's being called via a rest resource, I was trying to get to it directly, that's getting me closer.  Copied the rest resource above.  So now I'm just needing the json response.

Comment: @hippiecoder - Your future method updates the `mr.Last_Match_API_Update__c = System.now();` so to validate it worked, after stop test query for `mr.Last_Match_API_Update__c = System.now();` and assert that it was populated (assuming it was null before) - But first you need to set up your mock implementation as I do not see it in your test class

Answer (score 2):

Future methods are asynchronous so they cannot return a value (hence the `void` return type). Instead you need to do something in the future method with your HTTP response (like put it in the database). In your test, calling `Test.stopTest()` will ensure that the `@future` method completes. Then, you can query for the result you updated in the `@future` method to ensure the update took place successfully.

Comment: Ah!  That makes total sense.  Thank you, I'll mess with that then respond.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to make that happen.  Maybe you are meaning have a line in there about a system.assert?  I can modify the code around (and did) but still wasn't able to get any code coverage on this callout class.

Comment: There's a pretty good example in the [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm)